# Is my "hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11" something to worry about?

Tags: android, logcat, android-sensors, motorola

I get this error in LogCat while doing dev work. Sounds like a hardware malfunction. Is it? What's it in relation to? I tried searching but found only people talking about cameras. It's on a Motorola Razr M. My device acts quirky a lot (feedback delays often when unlocking and freezing temporarily while playing games) and I wonder if this has something to do with it. Thanks!

```
PID   TID    Application   Tag                  Text
698   710                  qcom_sensors_hal     hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11
```

(with some context)

```
06-30 09:32:52.693: D/PowerManagerService(698): acquireWakeLock flags=0x1 tag=AlarmManager
06-30 09:32:52.703: D/PowerManagerService(698): acquireWakeLock flags=0x1 tag=NlpWakeLock
06-30 09:32:52.703: D/PowerManagerService(698): releaseWakeLock flags=0x1 tag=AlarmManager
06-30 09:32:52.713: D/PowerManagerService(698): acquireWakeLock flags=0x1 tag=NlpCollectorWakeLock
06-30 09:32:52.723: D/PowerManagerService(698): acquireWakeLock flags=0x1 tag=NlpCollectorWakeLock
06-30 09:32:52.723: D/SensorManager(19005): caller of registerListener:19005,sensor type:1
06-30 09:32:52.723: I/Sensors(507): sns_pwr.c(383):sns_pwr_set_cpu_latency: hz 50
06-30 09:32:52.723: I/Sensors(507): sns_pwr.c(245):acquiring wakelock
06-30 09:32:52.723: D/PowerManagerService(698): acquireWakeLock flags=0x1 tag=NlpCollectorWakeLock
06-30 09:32:52.733: D/PowerManagerService(698): acquireWakeLock flags=0x1 tag=NlpCollectorWakeLock
06-30 09:32:52.733: D/PowerManagerService(698): releaseWakeLock flags=0x1 tag=NlpWakeLock
06-30 09:32:52.733: D/PowerManagerService(698): releaseWakeLock flags=0x1 tag=NlpCollectorWakeLock
06-30 09:32:52.743: E/qcom_sensors_hal(698): hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11 
06-30 09:32:52.763: E/qcom_sensors_hal(698): hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11 
06-30 09:32:54.595: D/ModemStatsService(1120): onSignalStrengthsChanged
06-30 09:32:54.595: D/ModemStatsService(1120): CDMA, mRssi=-93, mEcio=-140
06-30 09:32:54.595: D/StatusBar.NetworkController(919): onSignalStrengthsChanged signalStrength=SignalStrength: 99 0 -93 -140 -120 -1 -1 16 -117 -19 -70 2147483647 cdma 0 0 0 false 0 0 2 0 1 1 99 0 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 0 level=1
06-30 09:32:54.595: D/ConnectivityService(698): getMobileDataEnabled returning true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, it is to do with sensors. Unfortunately, I can't pinpoint the exact problem, but it is most likely a data accuracy issue with your accelerometer.

Android is a very complex operating system, and it is highly unlikely that every piece of native code functions exactly as intended. I wouldn't worry about this error.

Moreover, it is almost definitely not related to your phone freezing and having feedback delays. That sounds more like an issue of running low on RAM and processing power, while having too many background apps open. Try uninstalling the apps you don't use.

Comment: Thanks for the response. On a previous less-powerful phone (Galaxy Nexus) I had all the exact same apps with no problems. Perhaps Motorola is bogging it down with their crap though. I do note that in the above it refers to sensors with wake-up, power, and latency. I generally get the freezing immediately upon wake-up and trying to type in my pin then all is well for a while. Perhaps that's nothing though. Media player tends to junk up as well while playing music :-\.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to be getting no network location where I am currently at, and this message popped up in my log so suspecting this is part of my problem:

```
12-16 09:07:19.739  1117  1500 V GmsNetworkLocationProvi: onSetRequest: ProviderRequestUnbundled, reportLocation is true and interval is 0
12-16 09:07:19.739  1117  1117 V GmsNetworkLocationProvi: SET-REQUEST
12-16 09:07:19.739  1117  1117 V GmsNetworkLocationProvi: in Handler: ProviderRequestUnbundled, reportLocation is true and interval is 0
12-16 09:07:19.849   594   607 E qcom_sensors_hal: hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11
```

This sequence pops ups twice while opening Maps, so I am pretty sure the quality message pertains to the location somehow, likely throwing the network location away.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that is a bug related with the location:
http://www.reddit.com/r/Nexus5/comments/20g0vj/150_linessec_qcom_sensors_hal_logcat_spam_causing/
and it seems that this is only triggered if you have have chosen **not** to enable location reporting.
And once it happens it only stops after rebooting the device.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear data for Google Play Service.

Go to Settings > Apps > Google Play service > Manage space > Clear all data.
On my device that stopped these messages for a while (and so far, even when they reappeared they're much less frequent).