# What does hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11 mean?

Tags: android, adt, android-4.4-kitkat

I've established from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17391351/is-my-hal-process-report-ind-bad-item-quality-11-something-to-worry-about) that the error

```
E/qcom_sensors_hal(744): hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11
```

is not something to be immediately worried about. But does anybody know what it's coming from or what it means? Specifically, what is hal? (other than "I'm sorry I can't do that, Dave.") What might be going wrong? One never knows when I'll be outside the airlock and relying on my phone to get me in...

Here's some context in the verbose eclipse log, and I'm running a Nexus 5 with Kitkat, build v22.3. of ADT and Windows 8.1.

```
11-18 13:25:18.703: D/CrimeListFragment(31272): Crime #94 was clicked
11-18 13:25:19.643: V/QcrilMsgTunnelSocket(2548): After reading offset = 0 remaining = 4 countRead = 4
11-18 13:25:19.643: D/QcrilMsgTunnelSocket(2548): messageLength extracted from first 4 inputStream reads = 29
11-18 13:25:19.653: V/QcrilMsgTunnelSocket(2548): offset = 0 remaining = 29 countRead = 0
11-18 13:25:19.653: V/QcrilMsgTunnelSocket(2548): offset = 0 remaining = 29 countRead = 29
11-18 13:25:19.653: D/QcrilMsgTunnelSocket(2548): readRilMessage: Buffer = [B@42616ad0 HexData = [0100000004040000110000005155414c434f4d4def0308000100000000]
11-18 13:25:19.653: V/QcrilMsgTunnelSocket(2548): Read packet: 29 bytes. Data Available = 32 Position = 0
11-18 13:25:19.653: D/QcrilMsgTunnelSocket(2548): processResponse. message type = 1. Data Available = 28
11-18 13:25:19.653: D/QcrilMsgTunnelSocket(2548): ByteArray from parcel = 5155414c434f4d4def0308000100000000
11-18 13:25:19.653: D/QcrilMsgTunnelSocket(2548): Received RIL_UNSOL_OEM_HOOK_RAW message
11-18 13:25:19.653: D/QcrilMsgTunnelSocket(2548): Oem ID in RIL_UNSOL_OEM_HOOK_RAW is QUALCOMM
11-18 13:25:19.653: D/QcrilMsgTunnelSocket(2548): OEM ID check Passed
11-18 13:25:19.653: D/QcrilMsgTunnelSocket(2548): Response ID in RIL_UNSOL_OEM_HOOK_RAW is 525295
11-18 13:25:19.653: D/QcrilMsgTunnelSocket(2548): Response ID 525295is not served in this process.
11-18 13:25:19.653: D/QcrilMsgTunnelSocket(2548): To broadcast an Intent via the notifier to external apps
11-18 13:25:19.653: V/QcrilMsgTunnelSocket(2548): Before reading offset = 0 remaining = 4 countRead = 0
11-18 13:25:19.653: D/QcrilMsgTunnelIfaceManager(2548): handleMessage what=0
11-18 13:25:19.653: D/QcrilMsgTunnelIfaceManager(2548): Broadcasting intent ACTION_UNSOL_RESPONSE_OEM_HOOK_RAW

11-18 13:25:21.243: E/qcom_sensors_hal(744): hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11 

11-18 13:25:21.683: W/ProcessCpuTracker(744): Skipping unknown process pid 32352
11-18 13:25:21.683: W/ProcessCpuTracker(744): Skipping unknown process pid 32355
11-18 13:25:21.693: W/ProcessCpuTracker(744): Skipping unknown process pid 32365
11-18 13:25:21.693: W/ProcessCpuTracker(744): Skipping unknown process pid 32366
```

Comment: I see this error too and hoping it is not an issue with my Nexus 5. Almost sounds like a hardware issue.

Comment: I would expect "hal" to stand for Hardware Abstraction Layer in this context but that's only a wild guess. -- I wouldn't subscribe to the selected answer in [Is my “hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11” something to worry about?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17391351/1856738). If I were you, I'd have a look at the source of qcom_sensors_hal and/or (especially if it's not open source) contact the manufacturer.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an error message of a device component.