# Android in app: strange error

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I'm implementing the inapp purchase...
I've followed the Google guide, putted my app online in beta, subscribed my email to the beta.
The app respond me the price of the inapp correctly... but when i click on the button to purchase, it respond to me: impossible to shop the article. (error code IAB-LPD).

**Logcat Error :**

```
10:16:58.142     751-1791/? E/qcom_sensors_hal﹕ hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11
07-09 10:17:44.212     751-1791/? E/qcom_sensors_hal﹕ hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11
07-09 10:17:45.392     751-1791/? E/qcom_sensors_hal﹕ hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11
07-09 10:17:47.582     751-1791/? E/qcom_sensors_hal﹕ hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11
07-09 10:17:51.792     751-1791/? E/qcom_sensors_hal﹕ hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11
07-09 10:17:52.922     751-1791/? E/qcom_sensors_hal﹕ hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11
07-09 10:17:55.112     751-1791/? E/qcom_sensors_hal﹕ hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11
07-09 10:17:56.252     751-1791/? E/qcom_sensors_hal﹕ hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11
07-09 10:17:59.362     751-1791/? E/qcom_sensors_hal﹕ hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11
07-09 10:18:01.462     751-1791/? E/qcom_sensors_hal﹕ hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11
07-09 10:18:43.212    8220-8262/? E/Finsky﹕ [1428] FileBasedKeyValueStore.delete: Attempt to delete 'paramsUW0_kyxyYoEe83-zfLm9KQ' failed!
07-09 10:18:43.332    8220-8246/? E/Volley﹕ [1413] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for https://android.clients.google.com/fdfe/preparePurchase
07-09 10:18:43.582     751-1791/? E/qcom_sensors_hal﹕ hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11
07-09 10:18:46.682     751-1791/? E/qcom_sensors_hal﹕ hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11
```

and the **code** that call the inapp:

```
mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(Funzioni_aggiuntive.this, sku, 10001, mPurchaseFinishedListener, key);

IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase){
        if (result.isFailure()) {
            Log.e("Errore", "Error purchasing: " + result);
            mParse.alert("Attenzione!","Errore nell'acquisto, si prega di riprovare.");
        }else if (purchase.getSku().equals(sku)) {
            Log.e("IN APP", "FUNZIONI OK");
            findViewById(R.id.loading).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.loading_back).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            acquistaFA();
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    mParse.controlloUser();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, context.getClass());
                    intent.putExtra("faccio", "0");
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }, 500);
        }else{
            mParse.alert("Attenzione!", "Errore nell'acquisto, si prega di riprovare.");

        }
    }
};
```

i have no error displayed or crash appened, because the phone remain with the "google alert" for the inapp on screen, showing the error above.

Thanks to all

Comment: Is that url right `https://android.clients.google.com/fdfe/preparePurchase` server returns `500` which either means the url does not exist or the device has no internet connection.

Comment: i know what is error 500, and i have internet connection....
seems obvious

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is my "hal\_process\_report\_ind: Bad item quality: 11" something to worry about?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17391351/is-my-hal-process-report-ind-bad-item-quality-11-something-to-worry-about)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17391351/is-my-hal-process-report-ind-bad-item-quality-11-something-to-worry-about/27020972#27020972 about this particular error.